# Cordova: How to get width and height of app?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I need to use JavaScript to get the width and height of the window for my cordova android application.

I have tried `$(window).width() and $(window).height()` from the JQuery library but the results are temperamental:

I am testing on a Nexus 7 and when I open the app in portrait mode I get width = 600, height = 888.

When I rotate the device to landscape and recalculate the dimensions they do not change when they should have swapped and when I rotate the device to back to portrait I get width = 960, height = 528.

I am very confused by this output and it makes me think I am using the wrong code. I would be very grateful for help or suggestions.

Here is the function for getting the screen dimensions:

```
function getDimensions() {
    //Gets height and width of web browser
    var height = $(window).height(); 
    var width = $(window).width();

    //Stores dimensions in array of form [width,height] 
    var dimensions = [width,height];

    return dimensions;
}
```

Here is where I check the dimensions after rotation:

```
function onOrientationChange() {
    var dimensions = getDimensions();
    console.log("rotation width " + dimensions[0] + " height " + dimensions[1]);
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: I have edited to include my getDimensions() function

Comment: Sounds like you are calculating the width and height before the redraw appears resulting in a width and height of the window before rotation. How are you detecting the window redraw after rotation? *Edit*: Did you try using setTimeout inside of the callback for the check after the orientation event occurs?

Comment: Mmm...it seems ok. I also use `$(window)` in my cordova apps to get height and width. Where you call getDimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
I know this works on web browser

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with the [orientationchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange) **event**:

> The orientationchange event is fired when the orientation of the device has changed.

And the **Window.orientation** property which contains a number representing the current orientation(check the picture below for more details).

[image: window.orientation values]

**Notice!**: window.orientation returns undefined in desktop browsers. So pls test on an emulator or device.

**Solution:**

1. Attach **orientationchange** event to the global window object.
2. Check the **orientation value** and do some logic inside there.

```js
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", orientationChange);

function orientationChange() {
  switch (window.screen.orientation) {
    case "landscape-primary":
      //your function over here: getDimensions();
      break;
    case "portrait-primary":
      //your function over here: getDimensions();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not interested in the device orientation. I just want to know the dimensions.

Comment: You wrote this "When I rotate the device to landscape and recalculate the dimensions they do not change when they should have swapped and when I rotate the device to back to portrait I get width = 960, height = 528."

Comment: you have to check the dimensions on every orientation change to get the correct values

Comment: I tried running your code and it threw an error on the 'switch(e.orientation) ' line -- "Cannot read property 'orientation' of undefined."

Comment: I replaced it with window.screen.orientation you could also try it. Do you bind Croswalk into your App?

Comment: I am not sure what Croswalk is. I have tried implementing the window.screen.orientation but I get no output. I will try and do more testing to work out what is going on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When execute console.log(window.screen.orientation) it returns [object ScreenOrientation], not an integer.

Comment: I edited my code hope it work now with the string values